# search by county in here api without latitude and longitude

Tags: here-api

i want to use here api for location search in specific country
but problem is that i have to pass the county latitude and longitude to the search api
is there any way so i can send only country code with latitude and longitude 
to here search api

"addressFilter" parameter already search on city or state in country

but it work along with latitude and longitude

$url="https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_id=&app_code=&at=37.09024,-95.712891&q=pizza&addressFilter=Hawally

Comment: Maybe you can try to retrieve country's lat and long using geocoding with partial address (with country only or both city and country set) https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-partial-address and use them in your places request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send country code in q parameter itself with latitude and longitude as below :

```
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_id=XXXX&app_code=YYYY&at=29.330964,47.519325&q=KW
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: problem that i dont know the latitude and longitude for each country

Comment: some thing like this
https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv
will not work 
because api will search on specific   ( latitude and longitude )  not all country around it